# Vim language: send current word to CtrlP

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I know how to use CtrlP. I type ctrl+p, then I start to write file name, ... and so on. But, ... I am very lazy developer. I want to directly send to CtrlP current word. I know how to get current word:

```
let l:currentWord = expand('<cword>')
```

In Vim Language, ... I How can I send l:currentWord to CtrlP?

```
map <F6>  :call ComposerKnowWhereCurrentFileIs()<CR>
function! ComposerKnowWhereCurrentFileIs()
    let l:currentWord = expand('<cword>')
    let l:command = "grep " . l:currentWord . " ../path/to/composer -R | awk '{print $6}' | awk -F\\' '{print $2}'"
    let l:commandFileFound = l:command . ' | wc -l'
    let l:numberOfResults = system(l:commandFileFound)
    if l:numberOfResults == 1
        let l:fileName = system(l:command)
        let l:openFileCommand = 'tabe /path/to/project' . l:fileName
        exec l:openFileCommand
    else
        echo "Too many files :-( - use CtrlP ;-) "
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: map <F6> <C-P><C-\>w

Comment: Can I map inside a function?

Comment: Why do you want to do this inside the function?

Comment: Because the function do a lot of things (removed in this question). In some cases I DONT need to call CtrlP: in that cases I ask to composer the path of file grepping current word. But is not the case of this question =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<C-P><C-\>w
```

See `:h ctrlp-mappings`. You may map this combination:

```
map <F6> <C-P><C-\>w
```

In a function:

```
exe "normal \<C-P>" . expand('<cword>')
```

Comment: I dont need remapping.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of CtrlP and similar plugins is to provide an alternative command-line where you can refine your search as you type.

If you don't need fuzzy search and you already have the filename under the cursor… why not simply use the built-in `gf`?

-- edit --

In the gif below:

- I jump to `/path/not/knowable/BlaBlaClassName.php` with `gf`,
- I jump back to the previous buffer with `<C-^>` (unrelated to your question),
- I jump to the declaration of `BlaBlaClassName` in `/path/not/knowable/BlaBlaClassName.php` again with `<C-]>` thanks to a `tags`file generated with `ctags`.

[image: gf]

Comment: Well, ... if I am on BlaBlaClassName, how can gf open a file placed in /path/not/knowable/SomeFileName.php?

Comment: Aniway: the question is "send current word to CtrlP in VimL".

Comment: If you feed `BlaBlaClassName` to CtrlP, the chances of it suggesting a totally unrelated `/path/not/knowable/SomeFileName.php` are pretty slim. But, with the correct settings, `gf` on `BlaBlaClassName` will open `/path/not/knowable/BlaBlaClassName.php` instantly. See my edit. That said, if you have a `foo` class in a `bar` file, you have more important problems than fiddling with CtrlP.

Comment: Then use ctags. CtrlP is completely useless for your use case.

Comment: Too big project. Composer knows where files are.

Comment: Using ctags/cscope/GNU global/phpctags is the correct way to handle this situation. You may want to look into [Effortless Ctags with Git](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html) or a plugin like [Gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags).

Answer (score 3):

```
function! LazyP()
  let g:ctrlp_default_input = expand('<cword>')
  CtrlP
  let g:ctrlp_default_input = ''
endfunction
command! LazyP call LazyP()
nnoremap <C-P> :LazyP<CR>
```

(this could probably be simplified but I suck at vim syntax)

Comment: I tried that snippet in my .vimrc before posting it here, and it does the job.

Comment: Ok, I have not remapped <c-p> in CtrlP

Answer (score 1):

For that, you wouldn't use the `<C-P>` mapping, but the `:CtrlP` command, as that one takes parameters.

To build a mapping that passes the current word to the command, there are two approaches. Either directly insert the current word into the command-line (via `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W`):

```
:nnoremap <Leader>p :CtrlP <C-r><C-p><CR>
```

Or, in order to use `expand()`, build the Ex command via `:execute`:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>p :execute 'CtrlP' expand('<cword>')<CR>
```